# Confusion in Intersection of Images of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am somehow unable to understand the following relation.

> if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $S,T\subseteq X$ then $$f(S\cap T)\subseteq f(S)\cap f(T)$$

The main problem is I always end up in showing the equality rather than the subset-ness.

> **Example**
>   $f:X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}\rightarrow Y=\{y_1,y_2,y_3\}$ where $f$ is defined by $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y_1$,$f(x_3)=y_3$ and $S=\{x_1\},T=\{x_2,x_3\}$
>   Then clearly $f(S)\cap f(T)\subseteq f(S\cap T)$ does not hold,thus the equality is not possible.

But **My question** is where I am making mistake in following proof :

$$y\in f(S) \cap f(T)$$
$$\implies y\in f(S) \land y\in f(T)$$
$$\implies \exists x\in S \land \exists x\in T$$ such that $y=f(x)$
$$\implies x\in S\cap T$$
$$\implies f(x)=y\in f(S\cap T)$$
Hence  $$f(S)\cap f(T)\subseteq f(S\cap T)$$

Can you please correct me,?

Comment: The fact that $\exists x \in S \text {  and  } \exists x \in T$ does **not** mean that they are the **same** $x$.

Comment: Consider : "there is a number that is Even and there is a number that is Odd".

Comment: Does that mean if such $x$ exists then equality holds ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In line three, you use the same $x$ in both $S$ and $T$.  All that you know is that there exists an $x\in S$ and there exists a $z\in T$ so that $f(x)=y=f(z)$.  There is no reason that you need the same element in both $S$ and $T$, just a pair of elements with the same image.

In your example, $f(S)=\{y_1\}$ and $f(T)=\{y_1,y_2\}$, so $f(S)\cap f(T)=\{y_1\}$.  Then, when you take preimages in $S$ and $T$ of $y_1$, you get $x_1\in S$ and $x_2\in T$.  These are (of course) not the same element.

Comment: (+1) one thing I want to know whether $f(s)$ is the set of **exactly** all elements that are mapped from $x\in S$ ? I mean consider here f(S)={y_1}, what I want to know , is whether {y1,y2} can be f(S) or not,? (as it contains {y1} !)

Comment: This is a different question, so it would be better to start a new question if you want more details.  However, the short answer is $f(S)$ is exactly the set of images of points in $S$.  In other words, $f(S)=\{f(x):x\in S\}$.

Comment: @Michael if it is exactly the set of images then, dpes $f(x)\in f(S)$ necessary imply $x\in S$ ? (Like $x\in S \implies f(x) \in S$)

Comment: @MDesmond This is a different question, so it would be better to start a new question if you want more details.  The short answer is that the two things you describe are not the same.  No, if you know that $f(x)\in f(S)$, then you cannot conclude that $x\in S$ since there might be some other $y\in S$ so that $f(x)=f(y)$.  For example, if $S$ is the positive integers and $f$ is the squaring map, then $f(-2)=4\in f(S)$ since $f(2)=4$ and $2\in S$, but $-2\not\in S$.  On the other hand, the last line you write is correct (after correcting a typo), $x\in S$ implies that $f(x)\in f(S)$.